# Django-rest :send POST request with 2 foreign key

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, django-rest-viewsets

I want to post a data in a serializer, having 2 ForeignKey. 
I have these models:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pet = models.ForeignKey(pet)
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child, related_name='boys')

class Pet(models.Model):
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=40)
------------------,
Class PetSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = ('kind',)

class ParentSerializer(ModelSerializer):    
    pet = PetSerializer(many=True): 
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('name', 'pet')

class ChildSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    boys = ParentSerializer() 

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('first_name', 'boys')
```

My first question: Is it possible to get the output as:

```
{
    "first_name": "Peter",
    "boys": [
      {
        "name": "Bill",
         "kind": "dog"
        }
      ]
   }
```

My second question:And I am trying to send data to create a new model, by using this method:

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        clean_data = validated_data.pop('boys')
        child = Child.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for data in clean_data:
            Parent.objects.create(child=child, **data)
        return child
But I got this error: TypeError: Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use boys.set() instead.
```

Comment: is `boys` is foreign key of `Child` model?

Comment: boys is The related_name :attribute specifies the name of the reverse relation from the Child model back to Parent model.

Comment: For your second question, please provide your `validated_data` and check your code about `tracks_data` varibale. Also where is the `username` in the error. Please make your second question more clear.

Comment: Sorry. It was boys.set()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for your first question, you can use [source parameter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) in your `ParentSerializer` class:

```py
class ParentSerializer(ModelSerializer):    
    kind = serializers.CharField(source='pet.kind'): 
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('name', 'kind')
```